# Code not working when document.ready is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code below works fine on jsFiddle without `$(document).ready(function() {` and the closing brackets. (ex: http://jsfiddle.net/cEDYD/ ) but soon as I put the code on my webpage with the document ready it stops works. Am I missing something? I've included jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showDiv(element, pro2) {
        if (pro2.children("option:selected").val() == "cpl") element.show();
        else element.hide();
    }

    var myElement = $("div#pro2");
    var mypro2 = $("select#ptype");

    $("select").change(function() {
        showDiv(myElement, mypro2)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Works fine for me. Generally though you'd keep the function declarations outside the scope of the the ready function.

Comment: @jli - I prefer inside the scope of document ready if that's the only place they're used. Yes it makes the document ready look messier, but it can help prevent clashes with other code.

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess it's more of a preference thing in this case.

Comment: @jli so its working when you test it? what's a good javascript console to use? I'm using PhpDesigner to do all my coding editing

Comment: @acctman yeah its working for me. I just use the built in console for Chrome or if I'm using Firefox I use Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you wouldn't want this wrapped in a document ready handler?

Appears the DOM is not ready at the time your javascript is executing.

Check the javascript console. Google Chrome is excellent for JS debugging.

Comment: i do want it wrapped in one, the original sample code did now have a document ready and I wast trying to add it myself. I got it to work

Answer (score 0):

problem ended up being a mistype character in my css file. -thanks for the testing  guys

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle has a setting that automatically wraps the code in `document.ready()`.  That's why it works without the `ready()` in the jsFiddle (see where is says `onload` in the upper left panel).

`document.ready()` is needed in a regular web page unless you place the javascript after the body HTML.